# Creating a select menus in bash from an array

Tags: bash

I have a function I would like to create a select menus from. Problem I'm having is it stops after the first iteration. Any ideas?

```
individual_task_action () {
  echo
  echo
  echo "Conatiner Name:"
  mapfile -t tasksInCluster < <(aws ecs list-tasks --region $region --cluster $cluster | jq -r '.taskArns[]')
  for task in "${tasksInCluster[@]}"; do
    mapfile -t containerName < <(aws ecs describe-tasks --region $region --cluster $cluster --tasks $task | jq -r '.tasks[].containers[].name')
    select container in "${containerName[@]}" "Quit"; do
    case $container in
      "Quit")
      exit 0
      ;;
      *)
      break
      ;;
    esac
done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your default action is to break out of the menu

```
  *)
  break
```

so you quit the menu every times.

You need more entry like :

```
case $container in
  "Quit")
  exit 0
  ;;
  ec2-foo*)
     echo "$container"
  ;;
  ec2-bar*)
     echo "$container"
  ;;
  ec2-base*)
     echo "$container"
  ;;
  *)
  break
  ;;
esac
```